# Api information is not shown in the browser Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]
The api information is showing in the console but not in the browser. Before I asked and one user said that I have to put

```
*ngIf = "catServ.length"
```

and then

```
*ngFor = "let item of catServ"
```

as you can see it here

```
<div *ngIf="catServ.length">
    <h2 *ngFor="let item of catServ" class="text-3xl md:text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight leading-7 sm:leading-10 truncate" style="font-size: 20px!important;">
        {{item.nombre}}
    </h2>
</div>
```

But the console shows an error that did not recognize that.

this is my ts file to call the api from the server

```
this.http.get(this.apiserver.apiUrl + 'negocios/listadoTodos/?negocioCategorias=1').subscribe(deCat => {
      this.catServ = deCat;
    });
```

What can I do in this case? I want to see the information in the browser, and now is only showing in the console

Comment: Hi, can you please check how `catServ` is initialized. It should ideally be initialized to an empty array if you are checking the length. Http requests take time to respond and what could be happening is that it is rendering catServ before the response which is fine if catServ is intially a list/array. This is my best guess. Ofcourse we may need to see more code of that component to confirm this.

Comment: @Dylan it is initialized like this:

catServ;

How can I initilialized as empty array?

Answer (score 0):

Your questing does not clarify what you are actually trying to achieve.

Are you trying to get rid of the error?
Do you want to see the data in the browser window?

I am going to assume you want to get rid of the error first

Add `*ngIf="catServ && catServ.length"` to avoid getting the error before `catServ` is initialized.

You can check the network tab to see the requests and check if you are getting any data back from the server

```
<div *ngIf="catServ && catServ.length">
    <h2 *ngFor="let item of catServ" class="text-3xl md:text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight leading-7 sm:leading-10 truncate" style="font-size: 20px!important;">
        {{item.nombre}}
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Let me explain this better, the thing is I called the API but I only can show the information in the console with this code:

 this.http.get(this.apiserver.apiUrl + 'negocios/listadoTodos/?negocioCategorias=1').subscribe(deCat => {
          this.catServ = deCat;
          console.log(this.catServ);
        });

And when I use *ngFor="let item of catServ" I cannot see the information of my for array on the website

Comment: Make sure 'catServ' is an array and then add the *ngIf as I stated above to only show the div when there is data to loop through. you are getting an error in your console because catServ is null and you are trying to use the length property on that object. Your are not seeing the API data in your console, that is a error message.